# Qt Charts with buttons to multiple pages

Tags: c++, qt, charts, qtcharts

I have a few data visualizations (in main.cpp) and I want to have it so that it chooses which to display based on buttons pressed. Here is a piece of main.cpp:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

        // 1. Batting Averages!
   /*
        QBarSet *set0 = new QBarSet("Altuve");
        QBarSet *set1 = new QBarSet("Martinez");
        QBarSet *set2 = new QBarSet("Segura");
        QBarSet *set3 = new QBarSet("Simmons");
        QBarSet *set4 = new QBarSet("Trout");
        *set0 << 283 << 341 << 313 << 338 << 346 << 335;
        *set1 << 250 << 315 << 282 << 307 << 303 << 330;
        *set2 << 294 << 246 << 257 << 319 << 300 << 325;
        *set3 << 248 << 244 << 265 << 281 << 278 << 313;
        *set4 << 323 << 287 << 299 << 315 << 306 << 313;
        QBarSeries *series = new QBarSeries();
        series->append(set0);
        series->append(set1);
        series->append(set2);
        series->append(set3);
        series->append(set4);
        QChart *chart = new QChart();
        chart->addSeries(series);
        chart->setTitle("Batting Avg by Year");
        chart->setAnimationOptions(QChart::AllAnimations);
        QStringList categories;
        categories << "2013" << "2014" << "2015" << "2016" << "2017" << "2018";
        QBarCategoryAxis *axis = new QBarCategoryAxis();
        axis->append(categories);
        chart->createDefaultAxes();
        chart->setAxisX(axis, series);
    */
        // 2. Stacked Bar!
    /*
        chart->legend()->setVisible(true);
        chart->legend()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);
        QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
        chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        QPalette pal = qApp->palette();
        pal.setColor(QPalette::Window, QRgb(0xffffff));
        pal.setColor(QPalette::WindowText, QRgb(0x404044));
        qApp->setPalette(pal);
    */
        // 3. Line chart e!
        // Other options here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtcharts-customchart-example.html
     /*
        QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();
        series->append(0, 16);
        series->append(1, 25);
        series->append(2, 24);
        series->append(3, 19);
        series->append(4, 33);
        series->append(5, 25);
        series->append(6, 34);
        QChart *chart = new QChart();
        chart->legend()->hide();
        chart->addSeries(series);
        chart->createDefaultAxes();
        QFont font;
        font.setPixelSize(18);
        chart->setTitleFont(font);
        chart->setTitleBrush(QBrush(Qt::black));
        chart->setTitle("Barry Bonds HRs as Pirate");
        QPen pen(QRgb(0x000000));
        pen.setWidth(5);
        series->setPen(pen);
        chart->setAnimationOptions(QChart::AllAnimations);
        QCategoryAxis *axisX = new QCategoryAxis();
        axisX->append("1986",0);
        axisX->append("1987",1);
        axisX->append("1988",2);
        axisX->append("1989",3);
        axisX->append("1990",4);
        axisX->append("1991",5);
        axisX->append("1992",6);
        chart->setAxisX(axisX, series);
        QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
        chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    */

        // 4. Pie Chart!
        // Define slices and percentage of whole they take up
    /*
        QPieSeries *series = new QPieSeries();
        series->append("Vegetables",.40);
        series->append("Beans",.20);
        series->append("Fruits",.15);
        series->append("Seeds/Nuts",.10);
        series->append("Whole Grains",.15);
        QPieSlice *slice0 = series->slices().at(0);
        slice0->setLabelVisible();
        QPieSlice *slice1 = series->slices().at(1);
        slice1->setExploded();
        slice1->setLabelVisible();
        slice1->setPen(QPen(Qt::darkGreen, 2));
        slice1->setBrush(Qt::green);
        QPieSlice *slice2 = series->slices().at(2);
        slice2->setLabelVisible();
        QPieSlice *slice3 = series->slices().at(3);
        slice3->setLabelVisible();
        QPieSlice *slice4 = series->slices().at(4);
        slice4->setLabelVisible();
        QChart *chart = new QChart();
        chart->addSeries(series);
        chart->setTitle("What Derek Ate this Week");
        chart->legend()->hide();
        QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
        chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
*/

        // Create the main app window
        QMainWindow window;

        // Set the main window widget
        window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
        window.resize(420, 300);
        window.show();

        return a.exec();
}
```

I have commented out and split up each section. If I use charts.ui to place buttons, I'm not sure how to show and split up each visualization based on what is pressed

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a QStackedWidget, where you put each of your QChartViews.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html

Or (if you want to really replace the charts (means: series)) inside the chartView, then remove the existing series on each button-click and add the new one, corresponding to your data-set.
But I had just really bad experiences with that - the axis and the scaling have to be adjusted for each data-set. So, I'd recommend the first option.

Comment: ok sweet, I'll check that out. Another thing, I am wondering is if you need to delete Chart pointers in Qt? for example, in this guys example http://www.newthinktank.com/2018/07/qt-tutorial-3/ he does not delete any of his pointers. Do they delete when they go out of scope? Or is he leaking memory? Just wondering if Chart pointers are smart, or if I need to delete them in a destructor

Comment: For example, I have it working as a  Horiz *v = new Horiz(series);
    QChartView *chartView = v->makeChart(); but then I cant delete v; because it wont show the data. So how do I delete v? is there an "on window close" that i can use to free the pointer

Comment: Usually for Qt-objects you assign a parent while constructing the object.By default this can be a nullptr. Then you should care for destruction yourself. If assigned to parent, then when the parent destructs, the child does as well.